# Is there any way to force reload a page with a JavaScript query?

Tags: javascript

The title might be a bit misleading, but I don't know how else to explain it.

Basically I'm at this URL:

```
www.mysite.com/shop/6-dresses#filter=[manufacturer:4]
```

And I want to make a link that would change it to

```
www.mysite.com/shop/6-dresses#filter=[manufacturer:5]
```

(e.g. like `<a href="www.mysite.com/shop/6-dresses#filter=[manufacturer:5]"></a>`)

But it doesn't seem to load **unless** I click on it and **refresh** the page after.

Is there anyway I can alter the link code so that it forces to reload the page fully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have all you need here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location#Methods

Comment: I've seemed to hit a snag with this method. If I try to click on the link from a different page i.e /shop/ it will just refresh and not change the page. It works if there is already a fragment in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried window.location = "www.mysite.com/shop/6-dresses#filter=[manufacturer:5]"

Comment: He probably has, but it probably won't reload the page, as it's just the anchor fragment that changed.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between both links is the [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). That's why the page isn't reloading. The reason for this is [RFC 3986 - Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.4) (emphasis mine):

> When a URI reference refers to a URI that is, aside from its fragment component (if any), identical to the base URI (Section 5.1), that reference is called a "same-document" reference.
>
> [...]
>
> When a same-document reference is dereferenced for a retrieval action, the target of that reference is defined to be within the same entity (representation, document, or message) as the reference; therefore, a dereference should **not result in a new retrieval action**.

You're fighting against the browser's correct behavior, and implicitly **going against the user's expectations**. I suggest you change the URLs to something like this:

```
www.mysite.com/shop/6-dresses?filter=[manufacturer:5]#filter=[manufacturer:5]
```

This **will** result in a reload of the page, without being dependent on JavaScript. Stack Overflow uses a similar approach for linking to answers:

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/3483627/some-question/3483650#3483650
```